# Diferencia entre un if con llaves y sin llaves

Tags: javascript

Estoy practicando el método **reduce** y me sucede algo curioso.

Quiero que me muestre la cantidad de usuarios que hay en línea,
pero el método reduce me devuelve el valor `undefined`:

```js
let users = [
  {
    name: 'usser1',
    online: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'usser2',
    online: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'usser3',
    online: false,
  },
];

let usserOnline = users.reduce((cont, user) => {
  if (user.online) {
    cont++;
    return cont;
  }
}, 0);

console.log(usserOnline);
```

Pero si saco el `return` del bloque me dice cuántos usuario hay:

```
 let usserOnline = users.reduce((cont, user) => {
    if(user.online) 
        cont++
        return cont
 },0);
```

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Supongo que la última propiedad está en `false` la condición no se
cumple y por ello no retorna el valor, pero, ¿no debería mostrarme 2? por que ya dos condiciones se cumplieron, quisiera saber por que manda `undefined`.

Comment: pues, simplemente, estas usando mal el reduce. No tenes que tener un return dentro del reduce. mira la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: No está demás mirar [la sintaxis de `if`...](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Con mucho respeto, gbianchi, en la sección [descripción](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#descripci%C3%B3n), el primer ejemplo sí contiene un return. O te refieres a un caso más específico?

Comment: @Arriel si, para un caso donde la funcion es acumuladora de cada item en el array.. no es lo que quiere aca..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Claramente, tiene una diferencia. Aquí, si la sentencia `if` se cumple, ocurrirá el `cont++;` y el `return cont`, ya que las `{}` encierran a estas dos líneas de código. Aquí te ocurrirá error porque el `return cont` debe estar fuera del `if` para indicar que el resultado final que te va a retornar el `reduce` sea ese `cont`:

```
if (user.online) {
  cont++;
  return cont;
}
```

---

Y aquí, si se cumple el `if`, solamente ocurrirá el `cont++` y siempre va a retornar el `cont`. Esto sucede porque este `if` sin `{}` indicará que se ejecute solo la línea que esté debajo de ese `if`:

```
if (user.online)
  cont++;
return cont;
```

```js
let users = [
  {
    name: 'usser1',
    online: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'usser2',
    online: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'usser3',
    online: false,
  },
];

let usserOnline = users.reduce((cont, user) => {
  if (user.online)
    cont++;
  return cont;

}, 0);

console.log(usserOnline);
```

O también al lado derecho:

```
if (user.online) cont++;
return cont;
```

```js
let users = [
  {
    name: 'usser1',
    online: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'usser2',
    online: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'usser3',
    online: false,
  },
];

let usserOnline = users.reduce((cont, user) => {
  if (user.online) cont++;
  return cont;

}, 0);

console.log(usserOnline);
```

En pocas palabras, eso sería lo mismo que:

```
if (user.online) {
  cont++;
}
return cont;
```

```js
let users = [
  {
    name: 'usser1',
    online: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'usser2',
    online: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'usser3',
    online: false,
  },
];

let usserOnline = users.reduce((cont, user) => {
  if (user.online) {
    cont++;
  }
  return cont;

}, 0);

console.log(usserOnline);
```

---

Recuerda mirar como es la [**sintaxis del if**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Comment: Ohhh ya ya gracias !! Ya lo tengo clarísimo, bendiciónes !!

Answer (score 1):

Según tu última oración queda claro que el tema de los `if` lo comprendes (me parece que el título de tu pregunta es engañoso). Y que la pregunta principal es porque el resultado es `undefined` y no `2`

Partamos con un ejemplo distinto.

```js
function suma(a,b){
  let resultado = a+b;
  //return resultado;
}
console.log(suma(1,1));
console.log(suma(1,1) + 1);
```

Al comentar el `return` queda una función que retorna `undefined`, ya que no tiene retorno conocido. En el segundo caso retorna `NaN`, ya que `undefined + numero = NaN`

*(Quédate con esto en la mente)*

---

**Luego veamos qué pasa con `reduce`**

Lo primero que hay saber es que el primer argumento de la función `reduce` es **otra función**, y como toda función para que haga algo debe ser invocada.

Yo crearé una versión muy simplificada de una función reduce para números, para que veas cómo funciona el tema

```js
let users = [{name: 'usser1',online: true,},{name: 'usser2',online: true,},{name: 'usser3',online: false},];

Array.prototype.Custom_Reduce = function(funcion, inicial){
   let resp=inicial;
   for(let item of this){ //recorremos el array
      resp = funcion(resp,item);  //invocamos la función, aquí está el problema
   }
   return resp;
};

let usserOnline = users.Custom_Reduce((cont, user) => {
  if (user.online) {
    cont++;
    return cont;
  }
}, 0);

console.log(usserOnline);
```

Observa que el código es el mismo que el tuyo, solo que ahora usamos `Custom_Reduce`. Veamos que pasa en las últimas 2 líneas de esta función:

```
  resp = funcion(resp,item); 
}
return resp;
```

Ahora tienes que observar el array original y encontrar el último elemento de la lista, donde verás que es `online: false`. Entonces, como es `false` **no entra al `if` y por lo tanto esa función retorna `undefinied`.** *(como pasaba en el ejemplo inicial de la suma)*

**Y como ahí termina la iteración, este `undefinied` es el resultado final.**

---

### **¿Y qué pasa si la lista estuviera ordenada de modo distinto?**

Digamos que ahora en la lista los elementos 1 y 3 son `online: true` y solo el segundo es `false`

Probaré con el `reduce` de toda la vida y con `Custom_Reduce`

```js
let users = [{name: 'usser1',online: true,},{name: 'usser2',online: false,},{name: 'usser3',online: true},];

Array.prototype.Custom_Reduce = function(funcion, inicial){
   let resp=inicial;
   for(let item of this){ //recorremos el array
      resp = funcion(resp,item);  //invocamos la función, aquí está el problema
   }
   return resp;
};

let usserOnline1 = users.Custom_Reduce((cont, user) => {
  if (user.online) {
    cont++;
    return cont;
  }
}, 0);

let usserOnline2 = users.reduce((cont, user) => {
  if (user.online) {
    cont++;
    return cont;
  }
}, 0);

console.log(usserOnline1);
console.log(usserOnline2);
```

Ahora dan ambos `NaN`, porque en la segunda iteración retornó `undefined` y en la tercera retorna un `numero + undefined`. y como vimos al principio esto es `NaN`

Comment: Hey amig@ muchísimas gracias !! Increíble aporte 