# Por qué razón solo me está sumando los dos primeros números del array

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando sumar todos los números del array pero solo me suma los dos primeros, qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
let array = [5, 20, 5, 20];

array.reduce((total, num) => {

console.log(total + num);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque en un `reduce` debes retornar el acumulador

```js
let array = [5, 20, 5, 20];

array.reduce((total, num) => {
  console.log(total + num);
  return total + num;  //<--- Esto te falta
});
```

Cuando ocupas arrow functions, y la sentencia está en una sola linea SIN  los `{}`, te puedes ahorrar el `return`, ya que está implicito

```js
let array = [5, 20, 5, 20];

let res1  = array.reduce((total, num) => total + num); //VALIDO

let res2  = array.reduce((total, num) =>{  //VALIDO
 return total + num
});

let res3  = array.reduce((total, num) =>{  // NO VALIDO, tiene corchetes pero no tiene return
   total + num
});


console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
console.log(res3);
```

Mas información en esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/582637/301324

Answer (score 0):

En JavaScript, cuando una [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (conocido como función flecha `=>`) tiene una sola expresión, se puede omitir las llaves `{}` y el `return` para expresiones de una sola línea:

```js
let array = [5, 20, 5, 20];

let result = array.reduce((total, num) =>
  (total + num)
);

console.log(result)
```

Y cuando se usan las llaves (como en tu caso), se está definiendo un [**bloque de código**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) que pueden contener varias expresiones y/o sentencias, y vendría necesario usar la instrucción `return` para especificar el valor que se debe devolver:

```js
let array = [5, 20, 5, 20];

let result = array.reduce((total, num) => {
  return (total + num)
});

console.log(result)
```

Y pues, la razón por la cual solo se estaban sumando los dos primeros números del array, es porque no estabas devolviendo el resultado acumulado en cada iteración de la función `reduce()`, por lo que en cada iteración, el valor de `total` se mantenía igual al valor de la iteración anterior y solo se estaba imprimiendo en consola la suma del valor anterior con el valor actual y **no con las demás** (ahí el error del `NaN`). Entonces, necesitarías retornar la suma de los valores en cada iteración, así:

```js
let array = [5, 20, 5, 20];

array.reduce((total, num) => {
  console.log(total + num);
  return total + num;
});
```